# how to get the value of lat and lng from the json

Tags: java, android, json

I have a json response.I want to get the value of lat and lng from the json response.But i didn't get the values.Please Help me.Below is my response.

```
{
    "html_attributions": [],
    "results": [
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 9.493837,
                    "lng": 76.338506
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
            "id": "2730a3d7ab068d666e61a02ce6160b4cd21a38c7",
            "name": "Nagarjuna",
            "place_id": "ChIJr0-U4vSECDsRtiALUlgZOzI",
            "reference": "CmRcAAAA4yl72_x5llqvdshRJwuuntunXrYu33qdP5G7-I0CdHzcDsyd6wwqjxdNeqvT6vtRIoDoIk_WGNd62SYSoNEdBrpDrOcf5g5eZMj_vobhmF11mrujsQ_Yc7p-oGxQH0XtEhDNJdjQf_WlK_dRAckBzlA3GhQ_wzXs5RxoaxWDSEurm_R5syuovg",
            "scope": "GOOGLE",
            "types": [
                "hospital",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "State Highway 40, Kodiveedu, Alappuzha"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 9.500542,
                    "lng": 76.341017
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
            "id": "d5b6c81a53a346dea1263de7a777703bc72b8796",
            "name": "SYDNEY OPTICALS",
            "opening_hours": {
                "open_now": true,
                "weekday_text": []
            },
            "photos": [
                {
                    "height": 422,
                    "html_attributions": [],
                    "photo_reference": "CnRnAAAA_jg-NlSrVKkDOP7wXhPhvFTD8NW4A4aDI_Ptl3F9c_qt9QwdztNTG9Cr51uGIphpEUMyhsTfhhaa-TlfoL8MUEffbguZJ1AhKUwzfe7Mbrvm2KW8Y1EQXVw_3FglxA4LM1hqWJCK_AV4xcvOw1vuHRIQ8_keBYr29H8jK145RQ_PkRoUgPZ0qzcSNdIntc2ZI4WvBIR-TBQ",
                    "width": 630
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJl9tvIV6ECDsR7Cmf3KkIl-4",
            "reference": "CnRjAAAA3qhFUcb8P9akE8xw-KwfF6OU6qvy2cVX4Sg0qK_xCOfeUEyxoFgwof8rk-Z2BBJ7Z4m7ZTbfdp78wqFbeLfojQWPldq7XDfzX0pLScBSysebEp9P4XmrsAO5qyqSUveb5jWcJDkYiOLKgaKMzoWQphIQbldrdJ9iEDHkGiQ7tleNYxoUnjcjcynUDMftaErRUQbOn-GkWj0",
            "scope": "GOOGLE",
            "types": [
                "store",
                "hospital",
                "health",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "Mullakkal, Alappuzha"
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

This is the google api response i used for getting the list of hospitals.Anybode plese help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: Assuming you use JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript

Comment: I used java programming

Answer (score 0):

### Use these steps:

1. Create a model class for that Json Response
2. Use Gson to parse the response
3. Then create an object of the class
4. using the object get the data variable from the class

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can help.

First, validate your JSON with http://jsonlint.com/

Second, use this site to generate POJO: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
make sure that Annotation GSON and Source type JSON are clicked ON!
Copy your classes in to your project.

Third: use GSON in Android :) (Retrofit is good for this)

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you use the [json.org Implementation for Java](http://www.json.org/java/index.html):

```
String response = "{\"html_attributions\": [], \"results\": ...";
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject result = jo.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject location = result.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");
double lat = location.getDouble("lat");
double lng = location.getDouble("lng");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String response = "{\"html_attributions\": [], \"results\": ...";
                              JSONObject objResponce = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray arrayResults=new JSONArray(objResponce.getString("results"));
                            if(arrayResults.length()>0)
                            {
                                for(int i=0;i<arrayResults.length();i++)
                                {
                                    //--- get each json object from array -----
                                    JSONObject objArrayResults = arrayResults.getJSONObject(i);
                                    //--- get geometry json object from each object of array -----
                                    JSONObject objGeometry=new JSONObject(objArrayResults.getString("geometry"));
                                    //--- get location json object from geometry json object -----
                                    JSONObject objLocation=new JSONObject(objGeometry.getString("location"));
                                    System.out.println("Latitude :"+objLocation.getString("lat"));
                                    System.out.println("Longitude :"+objLocation.getString("lng"));
                                }
                            }
```